# Why are DynamoDB nested attributes limited to 32 levels deep?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

According to DynamoDB documentation, it supports nested attributes up to [32 levels deep](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-attributes-nested-depth).

I don't understand why there is a limit in depth as DynamoDB is a key-value noSql database.

Why is there such a limitation? Does it have to do with the implementation?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `search with depth attributes` and how this relates to the maximum nested depth.